# How do I add If else statement to a snippet

Tags: php, adsense

I found this great php code that will help me serve adsense ads only to search traffic.

I need help coding it so that if the user is not coming from search then another ad code is shown to the user.

This is the original code

```
<?php if (function_exists(‘from_searchengine’)) {

 if (from_searchengine()) { ?>

 INSERT YOUR ADSENSE/BANNER CODE HERE

<?php } } ?>
```

What I am looking to do is if the user is not from search show another banner code.

Can someone help me with editing the code?

Comment: Just write `} else { }`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's the best practise what you're doing but still:

```
<?php if (function_exists(‘from_searchengine’)) {
if (from_searchengine()) { ?>
INSERT YOUR ADSENSE/BANNER CODE HERE
<?php } else { ?>
INSERT ANOTHER AD CODE HERE
<?php } } ?>
```

but it looks better when you do that:

```
<?php
    $ad_code = "INSERT YOUR ADSENSE/BANNER CODE HERE";
    $another_ad_code = "INSERT ANOTHER AD CODE HERE";

    if (function_exists(‘from_searchengine’)) {
        if (from_searchengine()) {
            echo $ad_code;
        }else{
            // if not from search engine
            echo $another_ad_code;
        }
    } else{
        // if function doesn't exist
        echo $another_ad_code;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Echoing `HTML` code is also bad, unless he is never going to edit this code (it will be bad to `echo` it anyway, but not that much).

Comment: @Linek what would you do? i'd like to change my answer if it's worth it

Comment: He should have his ads code in a separate view dynamically loaded. Your answer is correct, the problem is on his side. He has logic inside a view which should be inside a controller or whatever he is using to generate `HTML`. The better way would be to set ad's name inside a variable and then call something like `include 'views/ads/' . $ad . '.html';`.

Comment: Awesome this worked.  What do you say its bad practice?   I will be serving double-click javascript code with its own php function with it.  This solution looks to be working.

Comment: @user3479218 by "bad practise" i meant splitting php `if(){}` statement with raw html by closing and then reopening it like `?> RAW HTML <?`. It's working but it makes code more complicated to debug etc. Anyway, you should consider using a method which @Linek presented in his comment. P.S. i'd be glad if you accepted my answer :)

Comment: @cyborg86pl thanks for explaining.  I am not a technical person at all.  I was just looking for a way to expand this tutorial.   http://scratch99.com/website-management/make-money-online/smart-pricing/avoid-smart-pricing-show-adsense-only-to-search-engine-visitors/ to fit my needs of serving another code.  I am not really sure what @ linek is even saying or how to implement that.  my code is not changing.

Comment: by not changing i meant once its on the header of my wordpress blog I won't edit it again